# in shell how to combine rows between two strings into one row

Tags: shell, awk, sed

in the bash shell, (bash ver on solaris 5.8 could be old),
using awk or sed how would i merge rows into one row between a "repeating" pattern:

[EDITED: to explain myself better)]

my file contains a lot of entries like these:

```
my-group<--------------------------(main entry)
<tab>group-code<spcaes>AXZ1<-------(sub-section under main entry)
<tab>description                    
<tab>state<spaces>CA
<tab>items
<tab><spaces>item_value_1
<tab><spaces>item_value_2
<tab><tab>header_3 <---------------(sub-section under sub-section) (can have upto 5th level)
<tab><tab>header_3_item_1<spaces>vlaue
```

I want this to be turned into:
new line starts each time first column of the  row contain alpha-numeric value. when it does not, then it should be appended as:-
all TABs replaced with one "|" and parameter and value separated by a ":"

```
my-group|group-code:AXZ1|description:|state:CA|items:something:something2|last-member-name:XYZ
my-group|group-code:PORTU1|description:|state:CT|items:something:something2|last-member-name:FQRTZ
```

how can i do that? only way i could think was to open file in memory and read line by line and do it. is that the only way or can there be a sed/awk command?

I am putting here the bash code i am trying to achieve this. (not working yet)

```
#!/bin/bash
myFile=$1

function trim ()
{
    local var=$@
    var=$(echo $var|sed -e "s/^\s*//" -e "s/\s*$//" -e "s/[ \t]/:/g")
   echo -n "$var"
}

newLine=''
i=0
while read line
do
    i=$[i + 1]
    [ -z "$line" ] && continue
   if [[ $line =~ ^[[:alnum:]] ]]   <-----this is not working....matching every line
        then
        newLine=$(trim "$line")
        match="matched ^a-zA-Z0-9"
    elif [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]] ]]
        then
        line="$(trim "$line")"
        newLine="${newLine}|${line}"
        match="matched ^tab/space"
    fi
    echo -e "line number=$i match=$match line=$line new-ine value-->"$newLine"<--"
    echo
done < $myFile
```

ty.

Comment: How are we supposed to know if "something" is a key or a value? "description" apparently has no value, but "items" does, when both are the only word on the line. How significant is the whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with the following sed script:

```
:a
N
s/\(\n\)    \([-a-z][-a-z]*\)/|\2\1/
s/\n  */:/
$!ta
s/:|/:/g
P
d
```

On your input it produces the expected output:

```
% sed -f script.sed data
my-group|group-code:AXZ1|description:|state:CA|items:something:something2|last-member-name:XYZ
my-group|group-code:PORTU1|description:|state:CT|items:something:something2|last-member-name:FQRTZ
```

where `script.sed` contains the previous script.

**Walkthrough**

```
:a       Label marking the start of our loop
N        Read next line of input
s/…/…/   If the structure matches a key:value declaration, translate it
$!ta      and return to a, to read the next key (unless we're at end of file)
s/:|/:/g Otherwise, clean the fields, 
P         print text gathered so far, 
d         and start a new cycle
```

Note that my sed does not recognise `\n` in the replacement text of a `s` command, this is why I have to save it in a group.

Comment: Is `something:2` desired in the output?

Comment: @n0741337 You spotted a failure, the new version hopefully works as expected.

Comment: sorry none of the answers work. sunos 5.8 SUNWcsu version (for sed) 11.8.0,REV=2000.01.08.18.12    _or_ either_ latest linux gnu sed ver : $ sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1

Answer (score 1):

I was toying around with GNU awk and `-v RS=`, and `gensub()` but seemed too much like the other answer.

Here's an awk command that makes the leading whitespace significant by using `-F"[[:space:]]*"`:

```
awk -F"[[:space:]]*" '
  NF==1 {if(b!="") print b; b=$1}
  NF==2 {b=b (b~/:$/?"":":") $2}
  NF==3 {b=b "|"$2":"$3}
  END {print b}' data
```

Here's the walkthrough:

- When `NF==1` print the last `b` or start the output line `b`
- When `NF==2` catch label-less fields and append them to `b` with the prior label.  Uses the ternary operator to decide when to prepend the ":"
- When `NF==3` format key/value pairs and append them to `b`
- In the `END`, print the final line stored in `b`

In other words, build a buffer line by line then output it when a new record is encountered or at the `END`.

---

Temporarily, here's a copy of the original question data:

```
my-group
    group-code                     AXZ1
    description
    state                          CA
    items
                                   something
                                    something2
    last-member-name             XYZ

my-group
    group-code                     PORTU1
    description
    state                          CT
    items
                                   something
                                    something2
    last-member-name             FQRTZ
```

Comment: it dint work. i just copy pasted on command line and ran replacing data by my datafile.

Comment: I'm not surprised.  Your data doesn't appear to have reflected what you originally posted.  You've added additional levels of record formatting w/o updating the desired output.  I tried this on both a mac in awk and linux with two different older GNU awks and it worked when `data` was a copy and paste of the old question data.  Please update the question with the more complicated inputs(including one w/o the commentary) and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank all the people who answered my initial question. I will accept one of your answers.

however this is what i worked out, and it works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
myfile=$1

function trim ()
{
    local var=$@
    var=$(echo "$var"|sed -e "s/^\s*//" -e "s/\s*$//" -e "s/[ \t]\{1,\}/:/")
   echo -n "$var"
}

newLine=''
i=0
linesInFile=$(wc -l $myfile|awk '{print $1}')
while IFS= read  line
do
    i=$[i + 1]
    [[ ! $line =~ [[:alnum:]\*] ]] && continue
    if [[ $line =~ ^[[:alnum:]] ]]; then
        if [[ $newLine != '' ]]; then
            echo $newLine
        fi
        newLine=$(trim "$line")
    elif [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]]{4,} ]]; then
        newLine="${newLine}:$(trim "$line")"
    elif [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]] ]]; then
        newLine="${newLine}|$(trim "$line")"
    fi
    if [[ $linesInFile -eq $i ]]; then
        echo $newLine
    fi
done < $myfile
IFS=$' \t\n'
```

Comment: Glad this works for you though it gives me output that doesn't match the desired output using GNU bash on a mac using the copy/pasted data.  If the original input file is 17 lines line, what should `$cfgFile` be set to?  In the future, if an answer doesn't work for you, be specific as to how they fail.  It will give you a better chance of getting an answer that works for you.